# how do I search an array of objects and return only those objects with certain uids in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object

I have an array of uids, and another array of objects. The objects structure is such that it has a name and a uid. I would like to search the array or objects, and return an array of those objects that match the uids from the first array. I was exploring using [undersore.m](http://underscorem.org/) but I'm not sure if this is appropriate.

Comment: I've not used underscore.m, but it looks very much like .js and that's a very good library for filtering and the like.  NSArray implements filteredArrayUsingPredicate, which is appropriate, too.  So is @rmaddy's answer, which might be easier to understand if you're new to predicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple loop:

```
NSArray *uids = ... // your array of UIDs
NSArray *objects = ... // your array of objects with a name and uid
NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
for (SomeClass *object in objects) {
    if ([uids containsObject:object.uid]) {
        [matches addObject:object];
    }
}
```

`matches` will contain the matching objects.

Obviously you need to change `SomeClass` to your actual class that has the name and uid. And I'm assuming your class has a `uid` property. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Wow, of course, it's that simple, don't know why i was having trouble with that